# NetworkInterface's getNetworkInterfaces() to JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, enumeration, jcombobox, network-interface

First Question

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

returns a Enumeration type.
each element of the Enumeration has a getDisplayName() method which returns a string such as en0, en1, vnic1 etc.
Now I would like to make these strings into a JComboBox. I'm Stuck trying to add these through

```
jComboBox1.setModel("Some code here");
```

One more question out of curiosity.. Why did the folks working on Java decide to use Enumeration instead of NetworkInterface?

Comment: *"One more question.."*  To ask one *more* question, it is necessary to ask a *first* question.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't simply adding string to JComboBox works.

```
jComboBox.add(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().en1.getDisplayName())
```

or if you want to handle it in model then write a class that implements `ListCellRenderer` and in its method `getListCellRendererComponent()` call your method of getting name and return that.

Comment: Nope, That won't work... The getNetworkInterfaces() object doesn't have a getDisplayName() method because it isn't a NetworkInterface type..

Comment: @Heartinpiece: I'm not aware of `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();` so can't write perfect line but you can handle just write code by which you get string.

Comment: @HarryJory, Thanks for your answer, I got a hint from your Answer, went through all the elements of the Enumeration and added each display name onto a vector, then I added the vector by using the 
`new DefaultComboboxModel(vector);`